# Can I select which license to use in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, licensing

My school provides me with 2 licenses for Matlab - one for teaching+education, and one for research.

If I wanted to do things "all right", I should use a different license for different things I do. However, moving/overwriting the license.lic file is not a suitably simple solution for me.

Is there a way to change the license Matlab uses (whithout removing the other)?

Comment: not really a programming question.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/commonly-used-startup-options.html. You want the "-c licensefile" startup option

Comment: Great, @Benoit_11, exactly what I was looking for! You should convert your comment to an answer ;)

Comment: Alright I just posted an answer thanks :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing/legal advice](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can!

When starting MATLAB from the terminal, you can specify startup options such as nosplash, nodisplay, etc and fortunately the license file you want to use.

For example (on Windows), using this

```
matlab.exe -c licensefile
```

will perform what you want. Note that `-c licensefile` is a valid syntax for all platforms.

More info [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/commonly-used-startup-options.html) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/startup-options.html#bt6_l1r)